# Check if one regex covers another regex

Tags: c++, regex, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I'm attempting to implement a text clustering algorithm. The algorithm clusters similar lines of raw text by replacing them with regexes, and aggregates the number of patterns matching each regex so as to provide a neat summary of the input text instead of showing repetitive patterns from the input text. In this attempt I ran into the need to find if one regex covers another.

Assume we are concerned *only* about regular expressions with '*' and '+' wild cards i.e. '*' meaning zero or more occurences of an alphabet, and '+' meaning 1 or more occurences of an alphabet. Also assume the character set to be ASCII.

For example:

```
1. AB covers AB
      This is straightforward.
2. ABC* covers ABC
      Because ABC* can generate: ABC, ABCC, ABCCC etc.
3. A*B+C* covers AB+C*
      Because A*B+C* can generate ABBC, AABBC, AABBCC etc. which covers
      all strings generated by AB+C*.
4. A+M+BC* covers AMM+B+C+M+BC*
      Similar to case [3] above.
```

Basically I'm looking for an efficient implementation of the following method which tells if strA (may contain a regex) covers for strB (may contain a regex). Note that there should also be a way to escape the regex characters '*' and '+' in the input strings strA and strB.

Method signature in C++:

```
bool isParentRegex(const string& strA, const string& strB)
```

My thinking is that a recursive approach is required for the implementation and it may be a bit complicated. But I'm curious to know if I could reuse existing implementations instead of re-inventing the wheel or if there are any other straightforward ways to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: Determine if two regular expressions could match for the same imput?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410256/regex-determine-if-two-regular-expressions-could-match-for-the-same-imput)

Comment: Like most things, this would be easier in Perl. :-)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: No, that's about overlap (is there _any_ input) and this is a subset question.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the simple regex grammar you propose, the solution is fairly trivial.

Take your more complex example, `A+M+BC* covers AMM+B+C+M+BC*`
You can rewrite it as `A{1,}M{1,}B{1,1}C{0,}` covers `A{1,1}M{2,}B{1,}C{1,}M{1,}B{1,1}C{0,}`

This leads us to the simple rule: `R1` covers `R2` if all symbols appear in the same order, all lower bounds of `R1` are less or equal to those of `R2`, and the upper bounds of `R1` are more or equal than those of `R2`.

Now there's one slight problem with the simple rule. `AB*C` covers `AC`, i.e. there's a possibility that an optional symbol appears in `R1` and not in `R2`. You can solve that by inserting a `{0,0}` in `R2` when there's an (optional) symbol in R1 that doesn't appear in the equivalent position in `R2`. E.g. `AB*C` does cover `AB{0,0}C`.

The "optional symbol" rule is an optimization. If the symbol in `R1` isn't optional, `R1` certainly doesn't cover `R2`. E.g. `AB+C` doesn't cover `AC`. Therefore there's no need to insert a `B{0,0}`. But if you do, you'll see that `A{1,1}B{1,}C{1,1}` doesn't cover `A{1,1}B{0,0}C{1,1}` since the `R1` lower bound on `B` (1) is more that the `R2` lower bound on `B` (0)

Comment: I think this is trickier than you're letting on; consider the case that `R1` is `A{1,}B{0,}A{1,}` and `R2` is `A{2,}`. In order to insert `B{0,0}` in the right spot, you need to split `A{2,}` up, which requires having done some lookahead in `R1`.

Comment: I hadn't considered `A{2,}` as input; the question stated `A*` and `A+` only. So your case could be `A+B*A+` versus `A+A+`, and then it's clear where you'd insert the `B{0,0}`. It could also have been `A+B*A+` versus `A*A+A+A*` (the latter is also equal to `A{2,}`) and then it's indeed not so clear.

Comment: I didn't mean `A{2,}` as input, I meant it as the result of your rewrite. (Oh, or did you mean that the insertion of `B{0,0}` would happen *during* rewriting? I'd been picturing it as a second step.) But even in `A+B*A+` vs. `A+A+` it's not so clear where to insert the `B{0,0}` unless you do some sort of lookahead or backtracking to consider *both* the possibility that the first `A+` corresponds to `A+A+` *and* the possibility that it corresponds only to one `A+`.

Comment: And... What if I have a ECMA-Regex with it's features? Your solution is not full.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like implementing a function for finding the minimal DFA from a given Regular Expression. Let's Assume that

DFA GetMinimalDFA(Regex r1) does that.

```
bool isParentRegex(Regex r1, Regex r2) {
    DFA a = GetMinimalDFA(r1);
    DFA b = GetMinimalDFA(Regex.OR(r1,r2))
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

Comment: The minimal DFA? I'm not sure that works: is the minimal DFA unique? And, computing the *minimal* DFA is not necessarily a simpler task than the original question. (In fact, I would guess that it is harder.) (EDIT: actually, [DFA minimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) is a known problem, so maybe not)

Comment: Typical Comp.Sci. answer, though: "I don't know the solution to this problem, but I can show it's just as hard as another problem" :P But yeah, the Wiki link shows that there's one unique minimal DFA. Still, `DFA.Equals(DFA)` is another hard function.

Comment: @MSalters, oh, yeah, I should've read it rather than skimmed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, this would be pretty simple. Step one is to normalize each regex by changing `A+` to `AA*`, `A*A` to `AA*`, and `A*A*` to `A*`:

```
sub normalize_regex($)
{
    local $_ = shift;
    s/(.)\+/$1$1*/g;
    1 while s/(.)\*\1(?!\*)/$1$1*/g or s/(.\*)\1/$1/g;
    return $_;
}
```

Step two is to convert the first regex from a regex that matches the strings themselves, to a Perl-regex that matches the normalized regexes that match those strings; for example, `AA*B` would be converted to `^AA*\*?B$`, meaning "start-of-string, followed by A, followed by zero or more A's, optionally followed by an asterisk, followed by B, followed by end-of-string":

```
sub regex_to_metaregex($)
{
    local $_ = shift;
    s/(.)(\*?)/$2 ? "\Q$1\E*(\Q$1\E\\*)?" : "\Q$1"/eg;
    return qr/^$_$/;
}
```

Step three needs no explanation:

```
sub does_regex1_cover_regex2($$)
{
    my ($r1, $r2) = @_;
    $r1 = regex_to_metaregex normalize_regex $r1;
    $r2 = normalize_regex $r2;
    return scalar $r2 =~ m/$r1/;
}
```

This returns a true value for your cases #1–3. It returns a false value for your case #4, however, because unless I'm really missing something, `A+M+BC*` does *not* cover `AMM+B+C+M+BC*`?

> Note that there should also be a way to escape the regex characters '*' and '+' in the input strings strA and strB.

I did not worry about that in the above code, but since you're only worried about ASCII, a preprocessing step could handle `\*` meaning `*`, `\+` meaning `+`, and `\\` meaning `\`, by translating them into single characters outside the ASCII range:

```
sub process_escapes($)
{
    local $_ = shift;
    s/\\\\/\x80/g;
    s/\\\+/\x81/g;
    s/\\\*/\x82/g;
    s/\x80/\\/g;
    return $_;
}
```

(though that's obviously rather hackish).

In C++, you can use the same approach — there exist libraries that implement all the necessary features of Perl regexes — though obviously it'd be a bit more work.

Comment: Can you tell more about Regex perl modules for C++projects?

Answer (score 0):

please check [this perl module source](http://search.cpan.org/~vbar/Regexp-Compare-0.17/lib/Regexp/Compare.pm) but remember it would not work for all regexps (as it will result in solving the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: The Halting problem applies to Turing Machines: regular languages (which are described by regular expressions) are much weaker than TMs, so it is entirely feasible that there is a general solution to this problem.

Comment: Perl "regex" isn't a regular language in the formal sense. See [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983115/are-perl-regexes-turing-complete). But yes, even those "non-regular regexes" are still weaker.