# Regexp pattern intersection

Tags: regex

Having 2 regexp's like a{anything}a and an{anything} how could I determine if they have a non-void intersection ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: Determine if two regular expressions could match for the same imput?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410256/regex-determine-if-two-regular-expressions-could-match-for-the-same-imput)

Comment: It kinda depends on the regex engine, too.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is undecidable for arbirary regex expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first regexp includes the second, so I guess you could make your 2 regexp like so:

```
a[^n].+
an.+
```

First one forbids n as the second character.
Second one imposes n as the second character.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn them into look-aheads and see if you get a hit:

```
(?=regex1)(?=regex2)
```