# Algorithm to find out whether the matches for two Glob patterns (or Regular Expressions) intersect

Tags: regex, algorithm, string-matching

I'm looking at matching glob-style patterns similar the what the [Redis KEYS command accepts](http://redis.io/commands/keys). Quoting:

> - h?llo matches hello, hallo and hxllo
> - h*llo matches hllo and heeeello
> - h[ae]llo matches hello and hallo, but not hillo

But I am not matching against a text string, but matching the pattern against another pattern with all operators being meaningful on both ends.

For example these patterns should match against each other in the same row:

```
prefix*       prefix:extended*
*suffix       *:extended:suffix
left*right    left*middle*right
a*b*c         a*b*d*b*c
hello*        *ok
pre[ab]fix*   pre[bc]fix*
```

And these should not match:

```
prefix*       wrong:prefix:*
*suffix       *suffix:wrong
left*right    right*middle*left
pre[ab]fix*   pre[xy]fix*
?*b*?         bcb
```

So I'm wondering ...

- if this is possible to do (implement a verification algorithm), if at all?
- if not possible, what subset of regex would be possible? (i.e. disallow * wildcard?)
- if it is indeed possible, what is an efficient algorithm?
- what are the time complexity required?

---

**EDIT:** Found [this other question on RegEx subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363397/how-to-tell-if-one-regular-expression-matches-a-subset-of-another-regular-expres/6364335#6364335) but this is not exactly the same as the words that `hello*` and `*ok` matches is not a subset/superset of each other but they do intersect.

So I guess mathematically, this might be phrased as; is it possible to deterministically check that a set of words that one pattern match, intersecting with a set of words that another pattern matches, result in a non-empty set?

---

**EDIT:** A friend [@neizod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889578/neizod) drew up this elimination table which neatly visualize what might be a potential/partial solution: [Elimination rule](http://pastebin.com/aBsGs5qd)

---

**EDIT:** Will adds extra bounty for those who can also provide working code (in any language) and test cases that proves it.

---

**EDIT:** Added the ?*b*? test case discovered by @DanielGimenez in the comments.

Comment: As I understand this question, you're asking if there's a way to determine if a pattern A matches a superset or subset of the words that another pattern B matches. Is that correct?

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes that's correct.

Comment: Out of my league, for sure, but looks like it's just plain hard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6364335/1394393. The part about "extensions" is probably referring to look around and modifiers like case sensitivity, but it doesn't sound like you need those.

Comment: Also, I don't think `hello*` and `*ok` have that kind of relationship. The first would match `hello world`, but the second would not. The second would match `grok`, but the first would not. So while they do have an intersection, neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes that is very similar but I'm looking to implementing something super simple. Much much simpler than a full-on RegEx. Just enabling the `*` operator, would suffice, for example.

Comment: @jpmc26 sry, you're right. it wouldn't be a subset, but would match. I think the better definition is that the set of words that A and B match intersect into something that's not an empty set.

Comment: Sorry if I got something wrong, I'm not too good at mathematics.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, but you could explore it. It seems that for them to have an intersection, the left and right anchors must be compatible (either non-anchored or one contains the other) and there must be a wildcard (in the middle if both sides are anchored). Any two patterns where one starts with a wildcard and the other ends with a wildcard will have an intersection. E.g., `foo*` and `*baz` will both match `foo bar baz` even though they have no common elements. `left*middle1*right` and `left*middle2*right` will also have an intersection. Maybe "has an intersection" is too broad.

Comment: If "have an intersection" is too broad, you might be able to do something with just splitting by the wildcard and testing if the different elements are compatible. You clearly want the anchors to match, for instance, and it seems you want middle elements to appear in both.

Comment: Maybe there's a better approach to your basic problem that doesn't involve comparing patterns. Maybe it would be worthwhile to step back and look at your end goal and ask about a way that doesn't involve something this intractable.

Comment: @jpmc26 unfortunately, I cannot avoid doing this :( ... but yeah if there's a better approach that might work (i.e. going around the regex engine altogether splitting on `*`) I'm all open.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410256/regex-determine-if-two-regular-expressions-could-match-for-the-same-input)?

Comment: @chakrit I think the pastebin link is all you need: if both have literal text on the left end, make sure it's compatible. if both have literal text on the right end, make sure it's compatible. If one of them has a `*`, the two expressions intersect. Of course, to check the compatibility you have to account for character classes and question marks, but that's just the question whether there is an intersection between two simple sets.

Comment: @Ross Presser not exactly. Related, but quite different.

Comment: @chakrit Wondering if you could add a couple of further examples for character matching? (E.g. if I've understood correctly, `pre[ab]fix*` should match against `pre[bc]fix*` but not against `pre[cd]fix*`?)

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes you got it right steve.

Comment: Just curious, Does "Totally*" match "*different"? Or does the pattern have to have something in common?

Comment: Is `[abcd]d => *d` true or false?
The left side can match `ad`, `bd`, `cd`, `dd`, where as the right side can match anything from `d` to `2314135a#QQ@Ed`.

Comment: @Daniel true Casperah yes they match.

Comment: @chakrit, why isn't either my answer or Steve's accepted?  We both produced code the demonstrates working methods.   What do you still need to mark one as accepted?

Comment: @DanielGimenez Sorry, didn't have the time to review them yet. I will get back to this shortly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

***Now witness the firepower of this fully ARMED and OPERATIONAL battle station!***

*(I have worked too much on this answer and my brain has broken; There should be a badge for that.)*

In order to determine if two patterns intersect, I have created a recursive backtracking parser -- when ***Kleene stars*** are encountered a new stack is created so that if it fails in the future everything is rolled back and and the ***star*** consumes the next character.

You can view the history of this answer to determine how arrived at all this and why it was necessary, but basically it wasn't sufficient to determine an intersection by looking ahead only one token, which was what I was doing before.

This was the case that broke the old answer `[abcd]d` => `*d`.  The ***set*** matches the `d` after the ***star***, so the left side would still have tokens remaining, while the right side would be complete.  However, these patterns two intersect on `ad`, `bd`, `cd` and `dd`, so that needed to be fixed.  My *almost* O(N) answer was thrown out.

### Lexer

The lexing process is trivial, except that is processes escape characters and removes redundant ***stars***.  Tokens are broken out into ***sets***, ***stars***, ***wild character (?)***, and ***character***.  This is different than my previous versions where one token was a string of characters instead of a single character.  As more cases come up, having strings as tokens was more of a hindrance than advantage.

### Parser

Most of the functions of the parser are pretty trivial.  A switch given the left side's type, calls a function that is a switch that determines the appropriate function to compare it with the right side's type.  The result from the comparison bubbles up the two switches to the original callee, typically the main loop of the parser.

#### Parsing Stars

The simplicity ends with the ***star***.  When that is encountered it takes over everything.  First it compares its side's next token with the other side's, advancing the other side until if finds a match.

Once the match is found, it then checks if everything matches all the way up to the end of both patterns.  If it does then the patterns intersect.  Otherwise, it advances the other side's next token from the original one it was compared against and repeats the process.

When two ***anys*** are encountered then the take off into their own alternative branches starting from each others' next token.

```
function intersects(left, right) {
    var lt, rt,
        result = new CompareResult(null, null, true);

    lt = (!left || left instanceof Token) ? left : tokenize(left);
    rt = (!right || right instanceof Token) ? right : tokenize(right);

    while (result.isGood && (lt || rt)) {
        result = tokensCompare(lt, rt);

        lt = result.leftNext;
        rt = result.rightNext;
    }

    return result;
}

function tokensCompare(lt, rt) {
    if (!lt && rt) return tokensCompare(rt, lt).swapTokens();

    switch (lt.type) {
        case TokenType.Char: return charCompare(lt, rt);
        case TokenType.Single: return singleCompare(lt, rt);
        case TokenType.Set: return setCompare(lt, rt);
        case TokenType.AnyString: return anyCompare(lt, rt);
    }
}

function anyCompare(tAny, tOther) {
    if (!tOther) return new CompareResult(tAny.next, null);

    var result = CompareResult.BadResult;

    while (tOther && !result.isGood) {
        while (tOther && !result.isGood) {
            switch (tOther.type) {
                case TokenType.Char: result = charCompare(tOther, tAny.next).swapTokens(); break;
                case TokenType.Single: result = singleCompare(tOther, tAny.next).swapTokens(); break;
                case TokenType.Set: result = setCompare(tOther, tAny.next).swapTokens(); break;
                case TokenType.AnyString:
                    // the anyCompare from the intersects will take over the processing.
                    result = intersects(tAny, tOther.next);
                    if (result.isGood) return result;
                    return intersects(tOther, tAny.next).swapTokens();
            }

            if (!result.isGood) tOther = tOther.next;
        }

        if (result.isGood) {
            // we've found a starting point, but now we want to make sure this will always work.
            result = intersects(result.leftNext, result.rightNext);
            if (!result.isGood) tOther = tOther.next;
        }
    }

    // If we never got a good result that means we've eaten everything.
    if (!result.isGood) result = new CompareResult(tAny.next, null, true);

    return result;
}

function charCompare(tChar, tOther) {
    if (!tOther) return CompareResult.BadResult;

    switch (tOther.type) {
        case TokenType.Char: return charCharCompare(tChar, tOther); 
        case TokenType.Single: return new CompareResult(tChar.next, tOther.next);
        case TokenType.Set: return setCharCompare(tOther, tChar).swapTokens(); 
        case TokenType.AnyString: return anyCompare(tOther, tChar).swapTokens();
    }
}

function singleCompare(tSingle, tOther) {
    if (!tOther) return CompareResult.BadResult;

    switch (tOther.type) {
        case TokenType.Char: return new CompareResult(tSingle.next, tOther.next);
        case TokenType.Single: return new CompareResult(tSingle.next, tOther.next);
        case TokenType.Set: return new CompareResult(tSingle.next, tOther.next);
        case TokenType.AnyString: return anyCompare(tOther, tSingle).swapTokens();
    }
}
function setCompare(tSet, tOther) {
    if (!tOther) return CompareResult.BadResult;

    switch (tOther.type) {
        case TokenType.Char: return setCharCompare(tSet, tOther);
        case TokenType.Single: return new CompareResult(tSet.next, tOther.next);
        case TokenType.Set: return setSetCompare(tSet, tOther);
        case TokenType.AnyString: return anyCompare(tOther, tSet).swapTokens();
    }
}

function anySingleCompare(tAny, tSingle) {
    var nextResult = (tAny.next) ? singleCompare(tSingle, tAny.next).swapTokens() :
        new CompareResult(tAny, tSingle.next);
    return (nextResult.isGood) ? nextResult: new CompareResult(tAny, tSingle.next);
}

function anyCharCompare(tAny, tChar) {
    var nextResult = (tAny.next) ? charCompare(tChar, tAny.next).swapTokens() :
        new CompareResult(tAny, tChar.next);

    return (nextResult.isGood) ? nextResult : new CompareResult(tAny, tChar.next);
}

function charCharCompare(litA, litB) {
    return (litA.val === litB.val) ?
        new CompareResult(litA.next, litB.next) : CompareResult.BadResult;
}

function setCharCompare(tSet, tChar) {
    return (tSet.val.indexOf(tChar.val) > -1) ?
        new CompareResult(tSet.next, tChar.next) : CompareResult.BadResult;
}

function setSetCompare(tSetA, tSetB) {
    var setA = tSetA.val,
        setB = tSetB.val;

    for (var i = 0, il = setA.length; i < il; i++) {
        if (setB.indexOf(setA.charAt(i)) > -1) return new CompareResult(tSetA.next, tSetB.next);
    }
    return CompareResult.BadResult;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rVp6/19/)

### Time Complexity

Anything with the words "recursive backtracking" in it is at least O(N<sup>2</sup>).

### Maintainability and Readability

I purposely broke out any branches into there own functions with a singular switch.  Assitionally I used named constants when a one character string would suffice.  Doing this made the code longer and more verbose, but I think it makes it easier to follow.

### Tests

You can view all the tests in the Fiddle.  You can view the comments in the Fiddle output to glean their purposes.  Each token type was tested against each token type, but I haven't made one that tried all possible comparisons in a single test.  I  also came up with a few random tough ones like the one below.

`abc[def]?fghi?*nop*[tuv]uv[wxy]?yz` => `a?[cde]defg*?ilmn[opq]*tu*[xyz]*`

I added an interface on the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rVp6/19/)** if anybody wants to test this out themselves.  The logging is broken once I added the recursion.

I don't think I tried enough negative tests, especially with the last version I created.

### Optimization

Currently the solution is a brute force one, but is sufficient to handle any case.  I would like to come back to this at some point to improve the time complexity with some simple optimizations.

Checks at the start to reduce comparisons could increase processing time for certain common scenarios.  For example, if one pattern starts with a ***star*** and one ends with one then we already know they will intersect.   I can also check all the characters from the start and end of the patterns and remove them if the match on both patterns.  This way they are excluded from any future recursion.

### Acknowledgements

I used **@m.buettner's** tests initially to test my code before I came up with my own.  Also I walked through his code to help me understand the problem better.

Comment: I have always wanted to see someone propose a proper parser for a pattern matching problem. =) +1 (Wish it could be more.)

Comment: This is insane. Very powerful, thank you for your hard work on this one.

Comment: If I wanted to update this code to handle cases like the ones below, what would be the best approach?

"hello.one.world" matches "hello.(one|two).world"
also
"hello.one.world" matches "hello.one|two.world"

Thank you!

Comment: @KirkOuimet, this is probably an SO question on its own.  I would start by creating the token types for alternation, scope open/close, and escaping characters.  Alternation will break things the most.  If a match fails then the parser will have to keep looking ahead to see if the alternation character exists, and then begin checking again where the scope starts.  Creating scopes might be simple, they're just indexes where the "(" is found.  If ")" is found and there is no scope then just treat it like a literal.  Comparing an alternation to an alternation will be the hardest case.Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

With your very reduced pattern language, the pastebin link in your question and jpmc26's comments are pretty much all the way there: the main question is, whether the literal left and right end of your input strings match. If they do, and both contain at least one `*`, the strings match (because you can always match the other strings intermediate literal text with that star). There is one special case: if only one of them is empty (after removing pre- and suffix), they can still match if the other consists entirely of `*`s.

Of course, when checking whether the ends of the string match, you need to take into account the single-character wildcard `?` and character classes, too. The single-character wildcard is easy: it cannot fail, because it will always match whatever the other character is. If it's a character class, and the other is just a character, you need to check whether the character is in the class. If they are both classes, you need to check for an intersection of the classes (which is a simple set intersection).

Here is all of that in JavaScript (check out the code comments to see how the algorithm I outlined above maps to the code):

```
var trueInput = [
    { left: 'prefix*', right: 'prefix:extended*' },
    { left: '*suffix', right: '*:extended:suffix' },
    { left: 'left*right', right: 'left*middle*right' },
    { left: 'a*b*c', right: 'a*b*d*b*c' },
    { left: 'hello*', right: '*ok' },
    { left: '*', right: '*'},
    { left: '*', right: '**'},
    { left: '*', right: ''},
    { left: '', right: ''},
    { left: 'abc', right: 'a*c'},
    { left: 'a*c', right: 'a*c'},
    { left: 'a[bc]d', right: 'acd'},
    { left: 'a[bc]d', right: 'a[ce]d'},
    { left: 'a?d', right: 'acd'},
    { left: 'a[bc]d*wyz', right: 'abd*w[xy]z'},
];

var falseInput = [
    { left: 'prefix*', right: 'wrong:prefix:*' },
    { left: '*suffix', right: '*suffix:wrong' },
    { left: 'left*right', right: 'right*middle*left' },
    { left: 'abc', right: 'abcde'},
    { left: 'abcde', right: 'abc'},
    { left: 'a[bc]d', right: 'aed'},
    { left: 'a[bc]d', right: 'a[fe]d'},
    { left: 'a?e', right: 'acd'},
    { left: 'a[bc]d*wyz', right: 'abc*w[ab]z'},
];

// Expects either a single-character string (for literal strings
// and single-character wildcards) or an array (for character
// classes).
var characterIntersect = function(a,b) {
    // If one is a wildcard, there is an intersection.
    if (a === '?' || b === '?')
        return true;

    // If both are characters, they must be the same.
    if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string')
        return a === b;

    // If one is a character class, we check that the other
    // is contained in the class.
    if (a instanceof Array && typeof b === 'string')
        return (a.indexOf(b) > -1);
    if (b instanceof Array && typeof a === 'string')
        return (b.indexOf(a) > -1);

    // Now both have to be arrays, so we need to check whether
    // they intersect.
    return a.filter(function(character) {
        return (b.indexOf(character) > -1);
    }).length > 0;
};

var patternIntersect = function(a,b) {
    // Turn the strings into character arrays because they are
    // easier to deal with.
    a = a.split("");
    b = b.split("");

    // Check the beginnings of the string (up until the first *
    // in either of them).
    while (a.length && b.length && a[0] !== '*' && b[0] !== '*')
    {
        // Remove the first character from each. If it's a [,
        // extract an array of all characters in the class.
        aChar = a.shift();
        if (aChar == '[')
        {
            aChar = a.splice(0, a.indexOf(']'));
            a.shift(); // remove the ]
        }
        bChar = b.shift();
        if (bChar == '[')
        {
            bChar = b.splice(0, b.indexOf(']'));
            b.shift(); // remove the ]
        }

        // Check if the two characters or classes overlap.
        if (!characterIntersect(aChar, bChar))
            return false;
    }

    // Same thing, but for the end of the string.
    while (a.length && b.length && a[a.length-1] !== '*' && b[b.length-1] !== '*')
    {
        aChar = a.pop();
        if (aChar == ']')
        {
            aChar = a.splice(a.indexOf('[')+1, Number.MAX_VALUE);
            a.pop(); // remove the [
        }
        bChar = b.pop();
        if (bChar == ']')
        {
            bChar = b.splice(b.indexOf('[')+1, Number.MAX_VALUE);
            b.pop(); // remove the [
        }

        if (!characterIntersect(aChar, bChar))
            return false;
    }

    // If one string is empty, the other has to be empty, too, or
    // consist only of stars.
    if (!a.length && /[^*]/.test(b.join('')) ||
        !b.length && /[^*]/.test(b.join('')))
        return false;

    // The only case not covered above is that both strings contain
    // a * in which case they certainly overlap.
    return true;
};

console.log('Should be all true:');
console.log(trueInput.map(function(pair) {
    return patternIntersect(pair.left, pair.right);
}));

console.log('Should be all false:');
console.log(falseInput.map(function(pair) {
    return patternIntersect(pair.left, pair.right);
}));
```

It's not the neatest implementation, but it works and is (hopefully) still quite readable. There is a fair bit of code duplication with checking the beginning and the end (which could be alleviated with a simple `reverse` after checking the beginning - but I figured that would just obscure things). And there are probably tons of other bits that could be greatly improved, but I think the logic is all in place.

A few more remarks: the implementation assumes that the patterns are well-formatted (no unmatched opening or closing brackets). Also, I took the array intersection code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885569/1633117) because it's compact - you could certainly improve on the efficiency of that if necessary.

Regardless of those implementation details, I think I can answer your complexity question, too: the outer loop goes over both strings at the same time, a character at a time. So that's linear complexity. Everything inside the loop can be done in constant time, except the character class tests. If one character is a character class and the other isn't, you need linear time (with the size of the class being the parameter) to check whether the character is in the class. But this doesn't make it quadratic, because each character in the class means one less iteration of the outer loop. So that's still linear. The most costly thing is hence the intersection of two character classes. This might be more complex that linear time, but the worst it could get is `O(N log N)`: after all, you could just sort both character classes, and then find an intersection in linear time. I think you might even be able to get overall linear time complexity, by hashing the characters in the character class to their Unicode code point (`.charCodeAt(0)` in JS) or some other number - and finding an intersection in a hashed set is possible in linear time. So, if you really want to, I think you should be able to get down to `O(N)`.

And what is `N`? The upper limit is sum of the length of both patterns, but in most cases it will actually be less (depending on the length of prefixes and suffixes of both patterns).

Please point me to any edge-cases my algorithm is missing. I'm also happy about suggested improvements, if they improve or at least don't reduce the clarity of the code.

[Here is a live demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oVACiXe/7/edit?js,console) (thanks to chakrit for pasting it there).

---

**EDIT:** As Daniel pointed out, there is a conceptual edge-case that my algorithm misses out on. If (before or after elimination of the beginning and end) one string contains no `*` and the other does, there are cases, where the two still clash. Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now to adjust my code snippet to accommodate that problem, but I can outline how to resolve it.

After eliminating both ends of the strings, if both strings are either empty or both contain at least `*`, they will always match (go through the possible `*`-distributions after complete elimination to see this). The only case that's not trivial is if one string still contains `*`, but the other doesn't (be it empty or not). What we now need to do is walk both strings again from left to right. Let me call the string that contains `*` A and the one that doesn't contain `*` B.

We walk A from left to right, skipping all `*` (paying attention only to `?`, character classes and literal characters). For each of the relevant tokens, we check from left to right, if it can be matched in B (stopping at the first occurrence) and advance our B-cursor to that position. If we ever find a token in A that cannot be found in B any more, they do not match. If we manage to find a match for each token in A, they do match. This way, we still use linear time, because there is no backtracking involved. Here are two examples. These two should match:

```
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: db?bdfdc
    ^                    ^
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: db?bdfdc
      ^                   ^
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: db?bdfdc
           ^               ^
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: db?bdfdc
             ^               ^
```

These two should not match:

```
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: dbabdfc
    ^                    ^
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: dbabdfc
      ^                   ^
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: dbabdfc
           ^               ^
A: *a*[bc]*?*d* --- B: dbabdfc
             !
```

It fails, because the `?` cannot possibly match before the second `d`, after which there is no further `d` in B to accommodate for the last `d` in A.

This would probably be easy to add to my current implementation, if I had taken the time to properly parse the string into token objects. But now, I'd have to go through the trouble of parsing those character classes again. I hope this written outline of the addition is sufficient help.

PS: Of course, my implementation does also not account for escaping metacharacters, and might choke on `*` inside character classes.

Comment: wow thanks for the extensive reply! I took the liberty and jsbin-ed your code over: http://jsbin.com/oVACiXe/3/edit?js,console .. will come back and read this over at end of day.

Comment: After re-reading your answer... and looking at that pastebin link again. I wonder if this can be done recursively which might be easier/ more clear&readable. (but yeah, it'd probably be less performant in the case of JS)

Comment: @DanielGimenez nice find for that test case!

Comment: @DanielGimenez oh, that's a good one. I think that might even be a conceptual flaw in my assumptions. I'll give it a closer look later on.

Comment: @chakrit I figured out the flaw in my algorithm and added an explanation for how to correctly treat these cases as well. It can be done in another linear-time step after eliminating both ends of the string. Unfortunately, I lack the time to actually add this to my implementation, but I've written a (hopefully) extensive description for how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

These special patterns are considerably less powerful that full regular expressions, but I'll point out that it *is* possible to do what you want even with general regular expressions.  These must be "true" regexes, i.e. those that use only Kleene star, alternation ( the | operation ), and concatenation with any fixed alphabet plus the empty string and empty set. Of course you can also use any syntactic sugar on these ops: one-or-more (+), optional (?). Character sets are just a special kind of alternation [a-c] == a|b|c.

The algorithm is simple in principle:  Convert each regex to a DFA using the standard constructions: Thompson followed by powerset.  Then use the cross product construction to compute the intersection DFA of the two originals.  Finally check this intersection DFA to determine if it accepts at least one string. This is just a dfs from the start state to see if an accepting state can be reached.

If you are not familiar with these algorithms, it's easy to find Internet references.

If at least one string is accepted by the intersection DFA, there is a match between the original regexes, and the path discovered by the dfs gives a string that satisfies both.  Else there is no match.

Comment: I don't know anything about automa theory, is there any way you can add a little psuedo code or something?  This problem was very intersting to solve, and I think I got it, but I don't think I could tackle anything more complicated.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Intersection DFA. Guess I gotta look that up. And yeah, some pseudo code would be nice.

Comment: @chakrit It's a coupld of hours' work I don't have time for right now, unfortunately.  The algorithms are not conceptually hard, but are quite detailed.  https://github.com/bniemczyk/automata has some of the pieces but not all.  The source code is commented in detail.

Answer (score 5):

Good question!

The main complexity here is handling character classes (`[...]`). My approach is to replace each one with a regular expression that looks for *either* exactly one of the specified characters (or `?`) *or* another character class that includes at least one of the specified characters. So for `[xyz]`, this would be: `([xyz?]|\[[^\]]*[xyz].*?\])` - see below:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Then for "prefixes" (everything before the first `*`), put `^` at the beginning or for "suffixes" (everything after the last `*`), put `$` at the end.

Further details:-

1. Also need to replace all instances of `?` with `(\[.*?\]|[^\\]])` to make it match either a character class or single character (excluding an opening square bracket).
2. Also need to replace each individual character that is not in a character class and is not `?` to make it match either the same character, `?` or a character class that includes the character. E.g. `a` would become `([a?]|\[[^\]]*a.*?\])`. (A bit long-winded but turned out to be necessary - see comments below).
3. The testing should be done both ways round as follows: Test *prefix #1 converted into regex* against prefix #2 then test *prefix #2 converted into regex* against prefix #1. If either match, the prefixes can be said to "intersect".
4. Repeat step (3.) for suffixes: For a positive result, *both* prefixes and suffixes must intersect.

**EDIT:** In addition to the above, there is a special case when one of the patterns contains at least one `*` but the other doesn't. In this case, the whole of the pattern with `*` should be converted into a regular expression: `*` should match against anything but with the proviso that it only includes *whole* character classes. This can be done by replacing all instances of `*` with `(\[.*?\]|[^\\]])`.

To avoid this answer becoming bulky I won't post the full code but there is a working demo with unit tests here: http://jsfiddle.net/mb3Hn/4/

**EDIT #2 - Known incompleteness:** In its current form, the demo doesn't cater for escaped characters (e.g. `\[`). Not a great excuse but I only noticed these late in the day - they aren't mentioned in the question, only the [link](http://redis.io/commands/keys). To handle them, a bit of additional regex complexity would be needed, e.g. to check for non-existence of a backslash immediately before the `[`. This should be fairly painless with [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but unfortunately Javascript doesn't support it. There are workarounds such as reversing both the string and regular expression with negative lookahead but I'm not keen on making the code less readable with this extra complexity and not sure how important it is to the OP so will leave it as an "exercise for ther reader". In retrospect, should maybe have chosen a language with more comprehensive regex support!

Comment: Check out the one I posted for @m.buettner.  It's a bit more helpful because I walked through what the matches should be.

Comment: Thanks again for the rigorous testing. Found a bug with the prefix/suffix when there is no wildcard that fixed the example in your comment above. However, the one you posted for m.buettner revealed a more serious flaw. In its most simple form, `a?` matched against `?b` is returning `false`. Will have a think about what to do about this and hopefully come back to it tomorrow...

Comment: @DanielGimenez Well that made things a bit more complicated! Have now updated the answer and fiddle with the extra use cases - now working for everything I can think of but please let me know if you find anything else...

Comment: Another one for you `?*b*?` => `bcb` is incorrectly true. Are you guy's treating `?` as valid for zero-length?  `?=b *=c b=b` and `*?` go unmatched.  I thought `?` would need to get matched.

Comment: Great spot! Looks like it's a special case when one of the patterns includes one or more `*`s but the other doesn't. Have edited my answer and fiddle + included these as extra unit tests.

Comment: I'll give you one more:  `return string.replace(/([\\\^\-])/g, "\\$1");` is incorrect.  You need to escape closing brackets too.  Bottom line: Your solution is very clever, but I think using regexes exposes your solution to more bugs, and if I keep trying I'll keep finding more failing cases.

Comment: Hmmm not sure about this. Was assuming a closing square bracket would *always* indicate the end of a character class after encountering an opening square bracket. Have now seen the [Redis syntax](http://redis.io/commands/keys) allows \ to escape characters but it's not clear to me whether this would be the case within a character class. Of course there may be bugs but the best way to deal with them is an interative approach, adding unit tests to try to cover all possibilities - going by the OP's comment: *"Test cases does not need to be exhausive, just enough for most trivial cases."*

Answer (score 0):

Determining whether a regex matches a subset of another regex using [greenery](https://github.com/ferno/greenery):

First, `pip3 install https://github.com/ferno/greenery/archive/master.zip`.

Then:

```
from greenery.lego import parse as p
a_z = p("[a-z]")
b_x = p("[b-x]")
assert a_z | b_x == a_z
m_n = p("m|n")
zero_nine = p("[0-9]")
assert not m_n | zero_nine == m_n
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd written this **Go project: [glob-intersection](https://github.com/yashtewari/glob-intersection)**, thanks mostly to the discussion here, back in 2017.

It's for regexp-style globs, so one would have to use `.*` instead of `*`, but all the examples given by @chakrit in their original post should work.